# Formatting Verbose Dates in Go

Tags: go

I would like to produce formatted dates in a human-readable format. Typically in an English locale, suffixes are used for the day of the month, i.e. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th and so on.

I tried using the format string `"Monday 2nd January"` to format such dates but it doesn't appear to work.

E.g. in [the playground](http://play.golang.org/p/PnzohanHar):

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

const format = "Monday 2nd January"

func main() {
    t1 := time.Date(2015, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, time.UTC)
    fmt.Println(t1.Format(format))

    t2 := time.Date(2015, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, time.UTC)
    fmt.Println(t2.Format(format))
}
```

This generates the result

```
Wednesday 4nd March
Sunday 1nd March
```

but I would expect

```
Wednesday 4th March
Sunday 1st March
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Even strftime doesn't support the suffixes.

Comment: Sad. A missed opportunity, perhaps?

Comment: Some years later, I implemented a solution myself
https://godoc.org/github.com/rickb777/date/view#VDate.Day2nd

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't support that kind of formatting, you will have to implement it yourself, something (hacky) like this:

```
func formatDate(t time.Time) string {
    suffix := "th"
    switch t.Day() {
    case 1, 21, 31:
        suffix = "st"
    case 2, 22:
        suffix = "nd"
    case 3, 23:
        suffix = "rd"
    }
    return t.Format("Monday 2" + suffix + " January")
}
```

<kbd>[play](http://play.golang.org/p/9szb7X1mum)</kbd>